# Should I create accessor methods in my JavaScript app

Tags: javascript

I used this form to structure my JS code

```
window.APP = window.APP || (function (global) {'use strict';
    return {
        operation: '',
        operand: 0,
        result: '',
        init: function () {

        }
    };
}(window.document));
```

There is better way like this:

```
var APP = APP || (function (global) {
    return {
        init: function () {

        }
    };
}(window.document));
```

But this way JSLint complains that APP was not initialized in the second call of APP, specifically this part: "var APP = APP"
So window.APP works and JSLint finds APP object in the window namespace.

If you check the first code block I have three application wide properties, operation, operand and result. I need those three accessible trough all my other subfunctions and subobjects. So far I used this form to access them:

```
window.APP.operand = global.getElementById("operand").value;
```

This works but the problem is, the code overall looks very ugly and cluttered with extra unnecessary text. In my 250 lines of code I have this "window.APP" prefix everywhere.

My questions is, should I create special accessor methods to get/set each of those properties or is there a better way to avoid that window.APP prefix?

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Notice that you shouldn't use `global` as a name for `document`, as "global object" is typically associated with `window`.

Comment: I don't understand what your question has to do with "accessor methods".

Comment: well how would you prevent using window.APP.propertyName every time,  except make accessor methods for porpertyName? But yes maybe Bergi's idea has a point, combined with closure if I return function that returns object instead of just return object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems promising:

```
var APP = APP || (function (global) {
    var operand = 0,
        operation = '',
        result = '';
    return {
        init: function () {

        }
    };
 }(window.document));
```

Have to try it though. I have some objects defined afterwards like

```
 APP.namespace('Aritmetic', {
     // properties/methods
 });
```

namespace function creates subobjects of APP. In the example above Aritmetic will become subobject of APP and will contain all properties methods defined in the second parameter of namespace() function.

I changed the second parameter of namespace function to this:

```
APP.namespace('Aritmetic', (function () {
     var parent = window.APP;
     return {
          test: function () {
              parent.operand = "2"; // all properties/methods from window.APP are accessible trough parent. 
          }
     };
}());
```

This might not be the most elegant solution to the problem but it works. If somebody knows better solution, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to mix the two approaches and use

```
var APP = window.APP || (function(doc) { "use strict";
    …
    return {…};
}(document));
```